# What would you call this type of function

Tags: functions, wolfram-alpha

[image: The Function]

I appreciate it if you could tell me what type of function it's called, and how do I put this function on my TI-nspire calculator or on Wolfram Alpha.

Thank you.

Comment: This is called a piecewise function

Comment: how is this different to $\sqrt{|x|}$

Comment: @Hushus46 Thanks!

Comment: @Chinny84 it isn't other than the domain, but wherever the linked picture came from is trying to teach piecewise functions I assume.

Comment: @Hushus46 thanks for that. Maybe we can say $\sqrt{|x|} -4 \leq x \leq 4$ ;)? But you seem right though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are called [Piecewise functions](https://www.mathsisfun.com/sets/functions-piecewise.html). They have different definitions, depending on the input domain.

**Note**. In that case though, it doesn't make much sense since it can simply be replaced by $$y=\sqrt{\vert x\vert}$$